# Are there any negative effects of calling glCompileShader multiple times using the same shader id?

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, glsl, shader

I am creating some classes to interface with OpenGL. One of them is `GLSLShader`. I want to `glCreateShader` in the contructor and call `glCompileShader` in a separate function called `compile`. So I wondered, if I call `glCompileShader` multiple times, would that cause a memory leak or any negative effects?

Comment: ¿Why would you call `glCompileShader` multiple times? It makes sense for any reasonable implementation to check compilation status prior to compiling shader. The only certain thing is that you'll get an extra call overhead.

Comment: Just in case I or someone else is stupid enough to do so and end up days or weeks debugging it just to find out it was that. I wouldn't do so under normal circumstances, but what if I forget the shader was compiled already and call compile again?

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto: "*I wouldn't do so under normal circumstances, but what if I forget the shader was compiled already and call compile again?*" This sounds like a really good reason to not have compilation be separate from construction. If doing a thing is a mistake, you should design your API such that this mistake cannot happen.

Comment: True, but the question still remains. If the ```glCompileShader``` can be called multiple times without any negative effects, I can sepearate ```glCreateShader``` and ```glCompileShader``` and leave it open for future growth. The current version of my class is designed as you suggest, but it becomes painful when passing my shaders to vectors and storing them for long term purposes because the get duplicated, so I have to use mad pointers and references, hence the reason for my question.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto: "*it becomes painful when passing my shaders to vectors and storing them for long term purposes because the get duplicated*" Don't make them copyable. Objects that are wrappers around OpenGL objects should be move-only.

Comment: *"it becomes painful when passing my shaders to vectors and storing them for long term purposes because the get duplicated, so I have to use mad pointers and references"* Now this makes this question an XY problem. You should ask about your original issue with mad pointers and references instead.

Comment: @user7860670 I have a function GLSLProgram::link(std::vector<GLSLShader>&.) which is fine but forces me to only have the shaders in the vector or use the emplace function and to create the shader right before linking it. It is a rigid approach that I want to solve. And I can't pass a vector of GLSLShader& because C++ does not allow it. That is when I reverted to you guys cause there are no resources on what would happen on multiple compilation on same shader id.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto: You should use a `std::span<GLSLShader>`, which allows people to avoid allocating memory just to pass a couple of shaders around.

Comment: I did not know that was a thing and I like. I'll consider implementing it. However, it would still force me to place everything in an array before putting into a span and potentially end up with duplicated shaders.

Comment: Well, if you are going to ask about issue with your  `GLSLShader` then it would be better to create a new question and to supply some real [mcve] code there rather than its vague description in the comment. There is nothing wrong with keeping shaders in the vector or in using emplace function. And it is not clear why use of `std::vector<GLSLShader>` will force you  to create the shader right before linking it.

Comment: The question is quite simple if you think about it. How I go about it with that information is totally irrelevant. A yes or no answer with a one sentence description will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `glCompileShader` on a shader object will perform compilation based on the strings currently in that shader, functionally replacing the shader's useful contents. If you compile a shader, don't change the strings, and then compile it again, nothing meaningful *should* happen.

However, most programs don't do this, so in terms of actual OpenGL implementations, this is code that rarely gets tested. So it is possible that this is more than a no-op. It could rerun shader compilation rather than doing nothing. It might even leak memory if there's a bug in the implementation.

In general, this should never come up. The only reason to compile a shader is if you have set the shader's strings. That is, the sequence of operations is *always* "set strings, compile", in that order. If you don't do the former, there's no reason to do the latter.

So don't let people do it. Your `compile` function should be *given* the string(s) to compile as parameters.